# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'domain name' (111)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im very new to php and my SQL, and am having trouble connecting to my SQL Database. Im getting the following error when i submit my HTML Form.

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'domain name' (111)
```

Here is my php code:

```
<? 

 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $email=$_POST['email']; 
 $location=$_POST['location']; 
 mysqli_connect("domain_name", "1645347_data", "*password omitted*") or die(mysql_error()); //error getting thrown at this line
 mysqli_select_db("1645347_data") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$location')"); 
 Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
 ?>
```

As you can see, it is a very simple php script (as I am following a tutorial).

Can anybody see why i would be getting this error? im more than happy to provide additional information if requested.

Comment: Is "1645347_data" a valid user name, and password is correct?
Is mysql service running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your script is trying to connect "domain_name", but it can't find that server because it's not listed on the DNS's. Is your server on the same machine? In that cause you need to replace domain_name with localhost, 127.0.0.1 or the ip of the server.

**ALSO MAKE SURE TO SANITIZE YOUR INPUTS BEFORE YOU RUN THE SQL COMMANDS!!!!**

[This should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)