# Connecting to MySQL from another IP/Website

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've newly set up a VPS and installed WHM.

I have a MySQL DB on this server which I am able to connect with using a desktop SQL application called Sequel Pro.

Using PHP I have set up a subdomain which I want to connect to this DB, I have used the same details as the Desktop Client but I keep receiving `PHP Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2003)` messages in my PHP error_log.

I'm completely stumped as I thought I would be able to connect to the DB from another website. I have add `%` to the **cPanel Remote MySQL®** and still no luck.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("HOST_IP","DB_USER","DB_PASS","DB_NAME");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
print_r($q);
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750724/mysqli-connect-hy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-domain-name ?

Comment: any firewall in your vps?

Comment: @maytham I've disabled ConfigServer but still no luck

Comment: Can you post how you've setup your DB connection in PHP?

Comment: @LloydBanks added to the post above

Comment: Can you post your my.cnf file? There could be a problem with the bind-address setting. One option that has security implications, but I'm usually fine with is to set it to 0.0.0.0 and thus bind to all IP addresses.

Comment: @Donald  I ran your code and it works fine for me.  What do you get as the output from the `print_r($q)`?