# Get Database details of a different server

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, mysqli, linode

I have error regarding of getting database details of a different server. I want to get the database details from the other server. I have tried this code but it shows this error.

Please check the below error :

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.81.134.56' (111)
```

Any way to solve this error it may be very helpful for me.

Comment: Speak to the DBA who owns the other database.  Your IP address might not have been GRANTed permission to connect.

Comment: What do you mean with "different server"? And how are you trying to access it?

Comment: Can you paste your connection code?

Comment: This is my connection code                                                                   $db_host        = '192.81.134.56'
$db_user        = '372-mysql';
$db_pass        = 'ZdKjVUcv';
$db_database    = 'demo_advert_live'; 
$db_port        = '61';

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database,$db_port);

Comment: @Nahuel lanni I have one wp site in one server and magento site in another server I need to get the db details of the magento site in the wp site server that only I need

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750724/mysqli-connect-hy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-domain-name
follow this method